# Are some enemies immune to the Ring of the Lucii?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

When you get the Ring of the Lucii and are forced to use it in Chapter 13, you realize that the ring is pretty OP (the AOE that takes some time to come out, Triangle on Playstation, one-shots a lot of stuff)

However, sometimes, the ring seems ineffective against some monsters.

Is there a miss rate or are some enemies immune to the Ring of the Lucii?

Comment: FWIW, Ring of the Lucii becomes your best friend when doing the "A Menace Sleeps" dungeons. Killing 3 Master Tonberries at once is quite handy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Ring_of_the_Lucii), instant Death is ineffective against some enemies, while Alterna has a random chance to miss.

- Death:

> Some rare enemies are immune to the instant death, but even most bosses are susceptible.

- Alterna:

> There are no enemies that are immune to Alterna, but the chance of it working is random and Noctis's Magic stat doesn't appear to affect it.
>
> After the 1.06 patch it has a chance of working even against superbosses and story bosses such as Adamantoise, MA-X Angelus-0 and the penultimate boss. The patch also improves the overall chance of it working on any enemy.

The Holy spell seems to work on all enemies, as the wikia does not mention any immunities.